# Unwanted interactions between 3 UILabels within UIPickerViews within UICollectionViewCells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uipickerview

Using pickers at the top of columns in a grid of UICollectionViewCells to control contents of each column independently: 
[image]

Each picker should update only the values of the cells in that column (only column 1 updated in image).
[image]

While the data updates, the label of the pickers become very confused!

1) When the user picks a new value at the top of column 1 or 4 - for example going from Masculine to Neutral.

1a) the data updates for the column - to Neutral - but the label on the used picker reverts to the previous value - Masculine.

1b) meanwhile, the label of the not selected picker (col. 1 or 4 - NOT 3) updates to the value selected in the selected picker (without changing the values in the not selected column)

In image, column 1 was updated from Masculine to Neutral (Das Kind is Neutral; den Ball is Masculine):
[image]

2) Column 3 is different when selecting a value.

2a) The data and picker label update correctly (no reversion to previous picker label value).

2b) If columns 1 and 4 have varying labels - eg col 1 Masculine, and col 4 Neutral they swap picker label values (no change to their data)!
[image]

I'm instantiating my pickers in a custom collection view cell from the collection view cell at item method. I'm using the indexPath.item to differentiate the cell and pickers (caseOfPickers) - that at least seems to control the data.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseI4CVCell, for: indexPath) as! CVCell

    switch indexPath.item
    {
        case 0, 2, 3:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseI4PickerCVCell, for: indexPath) as! PickerCVCell
            cell.caseOfPicker = indexPath.item
            cell.reference = self
            return cell
    ...
```

Then the whole of the custom collection view cell, where the picker is, is:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class PickerCVCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
{
var reference: EgPickerDelegate?
var caseOfPicker: Int?

private var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>?

@IBOutlet weak var pickerInCVCell: UIPickerView!

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    configureFetchedResultsController()

    pickerInCVCell.delegate = self
    pickerInCVCell.dataSource = self
}

private func configureFetchedResultsController()
{
    ...
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{ return 1 }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{ return 4 }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
{
    var pickerLabel: UILabel? = (view as? UILabel)
    let path = NSIndexPath(item: row, section: 0)
    if let gender = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: path as IndexPath) as? Gender
    {
        let text = gender.text ?? "Text not found"
        print("pickerText", text)

        if pickerLabel == nil
        {
            pickerLabel = UILabel()
            pickerLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
            pickerLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            pickerLabel?.font = pickerLabel?.font.with( .traitBold, .traitItalic)
        }
        pickerLabel?.text = text
    }

    return pickerLabel!
}

reference?.myPickerDidSelectRowInCase(selectedRowValue: row, caseOfPicker: caseOfPicker) }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{ reference?.myPickerDidSelectRowInCase(selectedRowValue: row, caseOfPicker: caseOfPicker) }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat
{ return CGFloat(120.0) }
}
```

Back in the custom class controlling the collection view, the picker delegate method is:

```
extension EgEndingsCVTVCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, EgPickerDelegate
{
func myPickerDidSelectRowInCase(selectedRowValue: Int?, caseOfPicker: Int?)
{
    switch caseOfPicker
    {
    case 0:
        col0GenderPredicate = genderPredicator(selectedRowValue: selectedRowValue ?? 0)
    case 2:
        col2GenderPredicate = genderPredicator(selectedRowValue: selectedRowValue ?? 0)
    case 3:
        col3GenderPredicate = genderPredicator(selectedRowValue: selectedRowValue ?? 0)
    default:
        col0GenderPredicate = genderPredicator(selectedRowValue: 0)
    }
loadSavedData()     // load data using new predicates
cView.reloadData()
}
```

Not sure why the labels of the pickers get confused - aren't they instantiated as individual objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because the entire collection view is reloaded at the end of the picker delegate method. When this happens, the UIPickerViews themselves are reloaded, and their current displayed status on the pickers (not the other values) become confused.

To update ONLY the existing collection view cells from rows 2 onwards without reloading the picker views, basically:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 4, section: 0)     // item 4 defines the index to column 1 row 2 
let cell = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell     // use the indexPath to get the existing cell at this position
cell.label.text = theNewText    // and just update this cell's label text.
```